# Easiest way to add/remove property to each object in a Javascript list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I have this object:

```
[
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
```

And I want this:

```
[
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe", "status":"Normal"  },
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith", "status":"Normal" },
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones", "status":"Normal" }
]
```

What's the easiest way to do it in Javascript ? Is there an one-liner way using one of the common libraries ? I know `jQuery.each(function...)`  will work, but I'm thinking there might be a better way. I'm also interested in the reverse, changing the second one to the first (removing the 'status' property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [{a:1},{a:2}];
array.forEach(function(object) {​​​ object["b"] = 3; });
```

Second one:

```
array.forEach(function(object) { delete object["b"]; });
```

Array.forEach is similar to Array.map, but it doesn't create a new array. You can also use this in older browsers by including the .forEach implementation provided on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: So you did :) Sorry, got confused!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map` method of Array.

```
var new_arr = arr.map(function(el) {
  el['status'] = 'Normal';
  return el;
});
```

Or for supporting the old browsers, use jQuery's map method.

```
var new_arr = $.map(arr, function(el) {
  el['status'] = 'Normal';
  return el;
});
```

***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/xBvhC/)***

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var key in persons)
{
    persons[key].status = "Normal";
}
```

I don't know a faster way than that.

Comment: and the other way around, just replace the in-loop content with `delete persons[key]['status'];`

Comment: But keep in mind that delete is only okay in objects. Don't use delete in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.forEach(function(item){item.status = "normal"});
```